# System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard works on desktop, but does not work on IIS

Tags: c#, image, iis, clipboard

I have a small module, which is looking for an image in the clipboard and if it is there, displays it on the page. This works great in my desktop, but never gets into System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ContainsImage() when hosted on IIS. Any concept that beats the purpose, like a windows clipboard cannot be used by server side application?

```
        if (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ContainsImage())
        {
            img = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage();
            imgBytes = imageToByteArray(img);
            string imgString = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length);                
            clipBoardImg.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgString;
            clipBoardImg.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Just look at `if (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ContainsImage())`. It literally says it uses the `Windows.Forms` namespace so it would never work on a webpage. Besides that, a webpage can only access your clipboard by client-side solutions. And even then it is up to the user if they will allow it or not, and the browser to support it.

Comment: Are you putting an image to clipboard on the server or on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to access the clipboard on IIS, you try to access it **on the server**, not on the client. This will most definitely fail server-side too since you don't have a screen in your server process (you are not user-interactive).

The thing you should do is convert this code to something client side (javascript for example), which is hard since you can't just access the clipboard from the clients browser.

I think it is (almost) impossible to get this implemented. Would the use of a `input type=file` help you? Or [a drag-drop surface](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/)? This seems the better options to me.

Comment: I have to say , I got to accept this as the answer, even though i am left with odd ways of achieving this. Just hought something out of native .net framework will click . Thanks anyway! Appreciate it

Comment: It provides in a way to interact with the browser. Nothing more.